# Not reaching part of async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async.js

I am trying to use async waterfall for the first time and am running into an issue where I have a function that is not being reached and it is timing out the request.

I have included all of the code for the controller I am trying to make/use. I have put a console.log in where I can't seem to reach as well.

So far the rest of the code is being run seemingly without error. I have done a console.log many times and everything is fine. I also checked the database and it is the correct result. The only issue is sending the email part but that should not be an issue since I use the same email send function in the same file and it works. I use it just before this one to send the email that contains the reset token.

```
exports.tokenPost = function(req, res, next) {

  let password = req.body.password;
  let password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;

  if(password != password_confirm) return res.status(400).json({message: 'Error passwords don\'t match. Please make sure they match'});

  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User
        .findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token })
        .where('resetPasswordExpires').gt(Date.now())
        .exec(function(err, user) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'We can\'t find a user with that reset token. Please try resetting your password again or contact customer support.'});
          }

          user.password = password;
          // user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
          // user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (err) return next(err);
          });
        });
    },
    function(user, done) {
      console.log('This code is not being run);
      let message = 'Hello,\n\n' + 'this is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n';
      sendEmail(`"Company Name" ${config.noreply}`, req.body.email, 'Password changed', message);
      res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Success your password has been changed.'});
    }
  ], function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) return next(err);

  });
};
```

I am expecting the email to be sent and then the `res.status.json` to be ran giving me the response I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong, when using async waterfall and you add `done` as a param for a function you have to call done in order for the next function to be called. I was not calling done when I was done saving the fixed user.

Also forgot the email part where I had to call the `user.email` compared to `req.body.email` since I don't have the email as a field on my form.